# login as regisered user in admin app | firestore SDK NODEJS

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Is there any way to initialize admin app with registered user.
So that i can try to write or read documents and assert my test result in test case.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, in Node.js (as well as in Java, Python and Go), you can use the `databaseAuthVariableOverride` option, when initializing the Firebase Admin SDK, in order to authenticate with the "limited privileges" of a given UID.

See the doc here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/start#authenticate-with-limited-privileges

Comment: But it is not working for Firestore https://github.com/firebase/firebase-admin-node/issues/132